# Where are Drupal (6) custom colour picker values stored?

Tags: drupal, css

I am using a Drupal theme which makes use of the colour picker.  When I select a new colour scheme, a directory gets creates in `MyDrupalSite/sites/default/files/color/ThemeName-RandomNumer`.  Using Opera's developer console, I can see that these files (the generated images and CSS) are used to render the website (if CSS caching is switched off, of course).  However, I have no idea where Drupal is told to look in that directory for the CSS: it doesn't seem to be in a config file and I have no idea where something like that might be stored in the DB.  I would also like to know where the colours for a "custom" configuration are stored: I spent a large chunk of last night trying to figure that out, but to no avail.  Are they somehow encoded into the "RandomNumber"?  So, if someone could enlighten me, I would be much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find that the color form on your theme saves the locations of the files as variables at the end of its save operation:

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/color_scheme_form_submit/6

```
  // Maintain list of files.
  variable_set('color_'. $theme .'_stylesheets', $css);
  variable_set('color_'. $theme .'_files', $paths['files']);
```

These values are then picked up by your color-aware theme. For instance, the Drupal 6 default theme (Garland) has the following in it's phptemplate_preprocess_page():

```
  // Hook into color.module
  if (module_exists('color')) {
    _color_page_alter($vars);
  }
```

This will add the CSS files to the header.